# How to make a dynamic slide up transition?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions, slide

I have got a task to create a multi-step accordion like a stepper form.

Each accordion will carry forms with the next and previous buttons inside of it.

On clicking the next button a new accordion will open from the bottom of the page, Initially it will be hidden, and clicking the back button will close the current accordion and opens the previous one.

I have created this one using the Slide component from React Material Ui, But this code contains hardcoded conditions inside of it. Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-step-accordion-forked-ip1lw3?file=/demo.js).

```
import * as React from "react";
import Accordion from "@mui/material/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@mui/material/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@mui/material/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";

export default function CustomizedAccordions() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (count < 4) {
      setCount(count + 1);
    } else {
      setCount(1);
    }
  };

  const nextButton = () => (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
      {" "}
      Next{" "}
    </Button>
  );

  const submitButton = () => (
    <Button
      disabled={true}
      variant="contained"
      color="success"
      onClick={() => console.log("success")}
    >
      {" "}
      submit{" "}
    </Button>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Slide
        direction="up"
        in={
          "panel1" === `panel${count}` ||
          "panel2" === `panel${count}` ||
          "panel3" === `panel${count}` ||
          "panel4" === `panel${count}`
        }
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Accordion
          expanded={"panel1" === `panel${count}`}
          onChange={() => setCount(1)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel1d-content" id="panel1d-header">
            <Typography>Step 1</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>{nextButton()}</AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Slide>
      <Slide
        direction="up"
        in={
          "panel2" === `panel${count}` ||
          "panel3" === `panel${count}` ||
          "panel4" === `panel${count}`
        }
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Accordion
          expanded={"panel2" === `panel${count}`}
          onChange={() => setCount(2)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel2d-content" id="panel2d-header">
            <Typography>Step 2</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setCount(1)}>
              {" "}
              Back{" "}
            </Button>
            {nextButton()}
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Slide>
      <Slide
        direction="up"
        in={"panel3" === `panel${count}` || "panel4" === `panel${count}`}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Accordion
          expanded={"panel3" === `panel${count}`}
          onChange={() => setCount(2)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel3d-content" id="panel3d-header">
            <Typography>Step 3</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setCount(2)}>
              {" "}
              Back{" "}
            </Button>
            {nextButton()}
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Slide>
      <Slide
        direction="up"
        in={"panel4" === `panel${count}`}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <Accordion
          expanded={"panel4" === `panel${count}`}
          onChange={() => setCount(4)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel3d-content" id="panel3d-header">
            <Typography>Step 4</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setCount(3)}>
              {" "}
              Back{" "}
            </Button>
            {/* {nextButton()} */}
            {submitButton()}
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Slide>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On Slide component u can see conditions like this

```
"panel1" === `panel${count}` ||
"panel2" === `panel${count}` ||
"panel3" === `panel${count}` ||
"panel4" === `panel${count}`
```

And each slide component and accordion carries this.

If I want to make this a dynamic, What refactor should I have to do in the code, and also please suggest to me, is there any way to create a similar UI like this in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, but before i show the code sample that i did:

1. The `in` prop from `slide` can be simpler -> in your example you can add some like: 
    `count >= ***Number of the step***`
2. It isn't wrong what you are doing with `nextButton` and `submitButton` functions. It's totally right, but I (and its just an opinion), think like -> Is this function just return a component? If yes, it shouldn't be a function inside my component but a component instead.

Said that, Let´s go to my sample code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Accordion from "@mui/material/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@mui/material/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@mui/material/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";

const ChangeStateButton = ({ variant, onClick, children }) => {
  return (
    <Button variant={variant} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

const SubmitButton = () => {
  return (
    <Button
      disabled={true}
      variant="contained"
      color="success"
      onClick={() => console.log("success")}
    >
      Submit
    </Button>
  );
};

// I've create an array that holds the steps
// (this could be a complex object an you can handle with it)
const steps = ["Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 3", "Step 4"];

export default function CustomizedAccordions() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  // CONST THAT HOLDS THE LAST INDEX FROM STEPS ARRAY
  const lastIndex = steps.length - 1;

  return (
    <div>
      {steps.map((step, index) => {
        return (
          // SHOW COMPONENT IF INDEX IS EQUAL OR BIGGER THEN COUNT (IN PROP)
          <Slide key={step} direction="up" in={count >= index} unmountOnExit>
            <Accordion
              // SET EXPANDED IF COUNT IS EQUAL INDEX
              expanded={count === index}
              // CHANGE COUNT TO THE INDEX SELECTED
              onChange={() => setCount(index)}
            >
              <AccordionSummary
                // SET ARIA-CONTROLS AND ID TO THE SPECIFIC INDEX
                aria-controls={`panel${index + 1}d-content`}
                id={`panel${index + 1}d-header`}
              >
                <Typography>{step}</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                {/* JUST SHOW BACK BUTTON FOR INDEXES BIGGER THEN 0 */}
                {index > 0 && (
                  <ChangeStateButton
                    variant="outlined"
                    // DECREMENT COUNT STATE
                    onClick={() => setCount((state) => state - 1)}
                  >
                    Back
                  </ChangeStateButton>
                )}
                {lastIndex !== index ? (
                  // SHOW NEXT BUTTON FOR ALL INDEXES, EXCEPET LAST ONE
                  <ChangeStateButton
                    variant="contained"
                    // INCREMENT COUNT STATE
                    onClick={() => setCount((state) => state + 1)}
                  >
                    Next
                  </ChangeStateButton>
                ) : (
                  // JUST SHOW SUBMIT BUTTON FOR LAST INDEX
                  <SubmitButton />
                )}
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </Slide>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*The code has comments and its pretty self explanatory, but if you have any questions, just ask.

And [here´s](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-multi-step-accordion-5ne858?file=/demo.js) the same code sample working to you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your component with the slide component, and use the same condition you use for `expanded` with `in` like so:

```js
          <Slide
            direction="up"
            in={"panel3" === `panel${count}`}
            mountOnEnter
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <TextField
              id="outlined-name"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              value={"test"}
            />
          </Slide>
```

Comment: I have done that. But it has a lot of hardcoded conditions. Is there any way we can make that dynamic